# PHP list of objects with foreach loop

Tags: php, list, foreach

Hi I am a C# developer and currently working a bit in PHP. I know this is a very simple task but I really don't have an idea for this. I have to create a list with the items to be dynamically created with foreach loop. These are the static list items that I want to create list dynamically with foreach loop.

```
        $item_1 = new Item();
        $item_1->setName('Item 1')
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(2)
            ->setPrice('15');

        $item_2 = new Item();
        $item_2->setName('Item 2')
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(4)
            ->setPrice('7');

        $item_3 = new Item();
        $item_3->setName('Item 3')
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(1)
            ->setPrice('20');

        // add item to list
        $item_list = new ItemList();
        $item_list->setItems(array($item_1, $item_2, $item_3));
```

Comment: Do you know how to write a loop? Do you know how to work with arrays? What exactly are you stuck on with this? Where would the dynamic data come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$items = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= SOME_NUMBER; $i++)
{
    $item = new Item();
    $item->setName('Item ' . $i);
    // ...
    $items[] = $item;
}

// ...

$itemList->setItems($items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array for that:

```
$totalItems = 3;
$itemsList = new ItemsList();
$items = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalItems; $i++) {
    $items[$i] = new Item();
    $items[$i]->setName("Item{$i}"); // Or "Item".$i; " - means PHP will search for variable inside (either with "{}" or without). ' - means PHP will ignore variables
    $items[$i]->setCurrency('USD');
    /* If all methods returns Item object, than you can chine methods calls: */
    $item[$i] = new Item();
    $item[$i]
        ->setName("Item{$i}")
        ->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setQuantity($this->getQuantity());
}

$itemsList->setItems($items);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$item_list = array();
foreach($data as $value){
    $item =new stdClass;
    $item->name = $value->name;
    $item->price = $value->price;
    $item->quantity = $value->quantity;
    $item->currancy = $value->currancy;
    $item_list[] = $item;
}
```